# FileZilla error Could not connect to server

Tags: filezilla

I was trying to connect to my hosting server and I received the error message as below:-

```
Status: Connection established, waiting for welcome message...
Response:   220---------- Welcome to Pure-FTPd [privsep] [TLS] ----------
Response:   220-You are user number 2 of 50 allowed.
Response:   220-Local time is now 11:40. Server port: 21.
Response:   220-This is a private system - No anonymous login
Response:   220-IPv6 connections are also welcome on this server.
Response:   220 You will be disconnected after 15 minutes of inactivity.
Command:    AUTH TLS
Response:   234 AUTH TLS OK.
Status: Initializing TLS...
Error:  Could not connect to server
```

I have tried on an off the firewall but still no luck. What could be the reason ? I have also tried with two different servers but it still isn't working.

Comment: Please move your question to [su]. It's [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) here.

Comment: Try port "21" instead of "80"

Answer (score 14):

In Filezilla Configuration: Site Manager choose Only Use Plain FTP, and Normal access mode

Comment: Selecting this setting worked for me. Although, until today, it was working with _"Use explicit FTP over TLS if available"_. I wonder why it stopped working, since I didn't update anything, as far as I know. Also, _"Only use plain FTP"_ has an "insecure" label. I don't know what it means here and I would prefer the default, less insecure, option that I've been always using.

Comment: Sorry to say, but did not help this solution to me. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I've encountered this problem before when trying to connect to my server. I solved it by going to *File* > *Site Manager...* and making sure all the settings in there were okay. Specifically, try these steps:

1. Make sure the host name is correct
2. Set the encryption to "Use explicit FTP over TLS if available"
3. Under the "Transfer Settings" tab, change the transfer mode to "Active"

Comment: Sorry to hear, I don't have much suggestions left. What port are you using? Try 21 or 22. Perhaps you could post this same question over at https://forum.filezilla-project.org as well.

Answer (score 2):

Usually, this error occurs when you have incorrect saved certificates in trustedcerts.xml at your local system. To fix this issue, you will need to remove/rename this certificate file from your system.

The file trustedcerts.xml contains certificates for secure websites that you have told your FileZilla client to trust connections to. This file should not be confused with any certificates you have in use if you use FileZilla as a server as well.

In order to remove a saved certificate from Windows System, navigate to %APPDATA%\FileZilla and delete OR rename the trustedcerts.xml file.

In order to remove a saved certificate from Linux System, navigate to ~/.config/filezilla/ and delete or rename trustedcerts.xml file.

Once you remove or rename this file, you will get the prompt to accept the certificate while you attempt to connect to FTP server through FileZilla. On getting the prompt of certificate, select "Always trust this certificate" and then accept it.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this just by removing port number. Now only by entering host, username, password it successfully connect and give the full directory listing.

Comment: Same fix for me -- I had 990 in the port number field, for FTP Explicit over TLS -- and it was just hanging and then timing out at the "waiting for welcome message" log entry. After removing the port number, everything started working fine.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me after rekeying my SSL certificate.  To fix it I had to rebind the FTP site in IIS with the new SSL certificate.